# Can I get a const slice_array from a const valarray?

Tags: c++, valarray

I have a function that accepts a const reference to a valarray, and I want to be able to slice the array and pass the slice into another function that expects a const slice_array. I know that I can just use operator[] and a slice to get a new, copied valarray out of the original valarray, but I want to avoid the copy. Everything is const, so I feel like that should be okay. However, the documentation for the subscript operator for valarray ONLY returns a slice_array objects when applied to non-const valarrays. This feels kind of a major deficiency in the valarray class. Am I missing something? How do I get a slice of a const valarray without incurring a copy?

Here is an example of what I'm talking about:

```
void foo( const valarray<double> &big_stuff )
{
    const slice_array<double> small_stuff = big_stuff[slice(start, size, stride)];
    bar( small_stuff );
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> How do I get a slice of a const valarray without incurring a copy?

There is no way to do this, because of `std::valarray` not contain `std::slice_array`
for any request, so it cat not give you just link(pointer,reference) to `std::slice_array` that you request.

But std::slice_array can contains only three machine words,
hard to imagine situation where not copy of `std::slice_array` can optimize something. For example from gcc/libstdc++ (only data, functions stripped):

```
 template<typename _Tp>
  class slice_array {
    const size_t      _M_sz;
    const size_t      _M_stride;
    const _Array<_Tp> _M_array;
  };
```

where _Array:

```
template<typename _Tp>
  struct _Array { _Tp* const __restrict__ _M_data; };
```